# Rotate an object around its center point in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to rotate a 3d game object around its center point in unity 3d.

Comment: I think I don't understand the problem. Transform.rotation = myTargetRotationQuaternion

Comment: in Update(): 

transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0,30,0); //degrees you want to rotate the object per frame. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Comment: or http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use

> Transform.rotation

look here for Examples/Documentation : 
[Unity Script Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

Comment: is that around  the real center point? I think no.

Answer (score 5):

Just use bounds.center from the renderer

```
Vector3 position = myGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

myGameObject.transform.RotateAround(position, rotationVector, degreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
```

where rotationVector is your rotation axis (Vector3)

Comment: You are the winner in my book / game. Real world solution.

Answer (score 2):

The two common ways to rotate an object are

1. The rotate attribute in the transform. Using this one you can set the exact coordinates for the target object rotation. However, you'll have to manage the smoothness by yourself if you want to make animations and the values are given through Quaternion type. I recommend to use the static method [Quaternion.Euler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) so you can pass values in a X, Y, Z.  The example below set the object to turn 90 degrees clockwise in the Y axis:

   ```
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0);
   ```
2. The second approach uses the Rotation method in the same transform attribute.  This method allow you to pass the amount of degrees in which object will rotate and already accept X, Y and Z coordinates instead Quaternion.
   The example below rotate the object 1 degree clockwise in the Y axis:

   ```
   transform.Rotate (0, 1, 0);
   ```

To best understand the difference between both methods, if you use the first one in an Update method you'll see the object static rotated 90 degrees in the Y axis.  The second example used in an Update will make the object spin clockwise in the Y axis (too fast).